# C# looping through Xelement

Tags: c#, json, xml

```
string webUrlCurrentGame = "";//usually the url 
var readerCurrentGame = JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(webClient.DownloadString(webUrlCurrentGame)), 
           new System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas());
var currentGameRoot = XElement.Load(readerCurrentGame);
string gameMode = currentGameRoot.XPathSelectElement("//gameMode").Value;
string championId = currentGameRoot.XPathSelectElement("//championId").Value;
string SummonerName = currentGameRoot.XPathSelectElement("//summonerName").Value;
```

The problem is there are 10 summonerNames in the XML how do I get the value from all of them ?

Comment: Please include your XML (or the JSON it was derived from) so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

with linq-to-xml often, if there's a singular verison of a selector, there's likely a plural version too.

In your case, `currentGameRoot.XPathSelectElements("//summonerName")` will return an `IEnumerable` which contains all the "summonerName" elements

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
string SummonerName = currentGameRoot.XPathSelectElement("//summonerName").Value;
```

to

```
var SummonerNames = currentGameRoot.Descendants("summonerName")
                             .Select(sn => (string)sn)
                             .ToList();
```

If you use `sn.Value` and `sn` is null, you will get a `NullExceptionError`.

Comment: Alright i have changed this but now im having problems returning the values. at first i used MessageBox.Show(SummonerName);

Comment: if you want to return values from a List<T> then use `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(",",SummonerName)`